# Using Symfony expression in 3rd party bundle configuration

Tags: symfony, parameters, configuration, expression

I am trying to configure HWIOAuth bundle to use dynamic client id. I have a service that can figure out what variable value to use depending on some request conditions.

Here's an expression in my HWI configuration, but can't seem to get it work:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names:
        - main
    resource_owners:
        auth:
            client_id:           "@=service('host.configmgr').GetClientIdParameter()"
            client_secret:       '%client_secret%'
```

The issue us with **@=service('host.configmgr').GetClientIdParameter()**. Can that even execute evaluate? The service is properly executes an used by another class somewhere else with success.

The %client_secret% parameter replacement works fine.

For more context, this part of the configuration lives in a dedicated file that is included in config.yml via **{ resource: hwiconfig.yml }**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research looks like expressions are only supported for service definitions. This functionality is not supported for configurations outside services like the HWI bundle config.